# Annoying JSON parsing Error index 2 out of range

Tags: java, android, json

Been trying to wrap my head around it for hours now and I always end up with this annoying ***Error index 2 out of range*** error

I know there's plenty of questions about the error in stackoverflow but everyone seems to have a different problem with their code

```
JSONArray platforms = currentMovie.getJSONArray("platforms"); 
for (int y = 0; y < arrayPlatforms.length(); y++) {
    JSONObject currentPlatform = platforms.getJSONObject(i);
    String platform = currentPlatform.getString("name");
    String platformAbv = currentPlatform.getString("abbreviation");

    platforms.add(platform);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+ platforms, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    platformsAbbreviation.add(platformAbv);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+ platformsAbbreviation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Both platforms and platformsAbbreviation are String ArrayList

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have a typo in:

`JSONObject currentPlatform = platforms.getJSONObject(i);`

That `i` should probably be a `y`.